# mysql err, mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: mysql

I have a problem after my macOS shut down, the mysql server doesn't start, and phpMyAdmin showing this error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Apache server starts normally on MAMP, but mysql is "dead".
I think the problem is in db, but I can't solve it.

```html
    170409 01:33:41 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/Apples-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
170409 01:33:41 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56
2017-04-09 01:33:41 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-04-09 01:33:41 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2017-04-09 01:33:41 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 5683 ...
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 8763118
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2017-04-09 01:33:41 5683 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_worker_info uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./mysql/slave_worker_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace wordpress/wp_term_taxonomy which uses space ID: 5 at filepath: ./wordpress/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd
2017-04-09 01:33:41 7fffd6a0a3c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./wordpress/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170409 01:33:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you just need to rename ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 as ib_logfile_0 and ib_logfile_1. Then your problem would be solved.

Comment: actually I've deleted the mamp and reinstal it..so thanks, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that it can't find the mysql socket. I had the same problem.

> Solution

```
grep mysqli.default_socket $(locate php.ini)
grep pdo_mysql.default_socket $(locate php.ini)
grep /etc/my.cnf
```

See if mysqli.default_socket and pdo_mysql.default_socket in php.ini and socket value under [mysqld] in my.cnf is matching

If not then update one of them or the empty one.

This worked for me